# Aligning equation on two lines

Tags: equations, align

I have an equation of this kind:

```
\begin{equation*}
A_1 \rightarrow A_2 \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow A_N 
\end{equation*}
```

And I would like to add a $B_1$ under $A_1$, $B_2$ under $A_2$ and $B_N$ under $A_N$. My idea was to use the environment `align`:

```
\begin{align*}
&A_1 \rightarrow &A_2 \rightarrow \dots &\rightarrow A_N \\
&B_1 &B_2 &B_3
\end{align*}
```

However it does not work as I was imagined. I would like to find a way to keep the equation above unchanged somehow.

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd keep the `equation*` environment and use bespoke `array` environments to place `B_1` below `A_1`, `B_2` below `A_2`, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'equation*' env.
%% macro with a bespoke 'array' env.:
\newcommand\mybox[2]{\begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}
                        \displaystyle #1 \\ \displaystyle #2 
                     \end{array}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
A_1 \rightarrow A_2 \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow A_N 
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\mybox{A_1}{B_1} \to \mybox{A_2}{B_2} \to \dots \to \mybox{A_N}{B_N}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know the environment array!

Answer (score 6):

It's easy with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1em,row sep=-0.5ex]
  A_1 \arrow[r] &
  A_2 \arrow[r] &
  \cdots \arrow[r] &
  A_N
\\
  B_1 & B_2 & & B_N
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `underset` command. MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \underset{B_1}{A_1} \rightarrow \underset{B_2}{A_2} \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow \underset{B_N}{A_N} \\
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem with \underset is that it reduces the sizes of $B_1$, $B_2$ and $B_N$...

Comment: Should be solved by inserting \displaymath where desired.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution with `equation*` and `stackengine`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{equation*}\stackMath\renewcommand{\Sstackgap}{3\jot}
    \stackunder{A_1}{B_1} \longrightarrow \stackunder{A_2}{B_2} 
    \longrightarrow \dots \longrightarrow \stackunder{A_N}{B_N}
    \end{equation*}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Really cool! Never heard of it before!

Comment: Thank you for your kind appreciation! Stackengine is indeed a very useful package.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the `IEEEeqnarray*` environment from the [`IEEEtrantools`](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{c'c'c'c'c} % ' provides 1em separation between columns. You may use other glues for shorter or wider separation
A_1 & \rightarrow & A_2 & \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow & A_N \\
B_1 & & B_2 & & B_3
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The spacing around the `\to` arrows isn't even. Is there a way to make the spacing more even?

Comment: @Mico Do you mean the spacing around the dots? That's possible using additional columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wasn't aware of this!

Comment: @Imran - II was referring to the fact that there's more whitespace around the arrows in `A_1 & \rightarrow & A_2` than in `\rightarrow \dots \rightarrow`.

Comment: @Mico I don't know. They should be the same though.

Answer (score 2):

With `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tblr}{cells=c, colsep=2pt}
A_1 & \to & A_2 & \to & \cdots & \to & A_N \\
B_1 &     & B_2 &     &        &     & B_3
\end{tblr}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]